# Steam Blank Boxes on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: steam

I am using Steam on Ubuntu 20.04 and have missing fonts (blank white boxes instead of letters) I cannot find a fix anywhere, Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a font substitution issue - unfortunately figuring out whether it's in the game or the OS is not easy. If it's in the OS, then you could try such as Deja Vu or Noto to see if they will substitute correctly. If it's in the game, the devs will need to fix it. [I'm ex-online support for a game with similar issues.]

Comment: @Tetsujin it's not an issue in game but a Issue in steam, the bar up top where the library buttons and stuff are.

Comment: For the purposes of this issue, Steam qualifies as "a game".

Answer (score 0):

Try re-generating `fontconfig`'s font cache:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install fontconfig
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

If that doesn't work, you may also be needing `fonts-liberation`:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install fontconfig fonts-liberation
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Alternatively, you could try `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install fontconfig ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Comment: Everything you suggested was already installed meaning issue is not fixed.

Comment: Have you actually tried the solution? Your comment sort of sounds like you dismissed the solution without even trying it

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I tried each one by one (restarting & checking steam after trying every one)